# Let $f(z)=2ize^{(i+1)z^2+2i}$. Find $\max_{z\in \bar{B}(0,2)}|f(z)|$.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

> Let $f(z)=2ize^{(i+1)z^2+2i}$. Find $\max_{z\in \bar{B}(0,2)}|f(z)|$.

My attempt:

Let $z=re^{i\theta}, 0\le r\le 2, \theta\in[0,2\pi[.$ Then $f(z)=2ire^{i\theta}e^{(i+1)r^2e^{2i\theta}+2i }$ and thus, $$ |f(z)|=2re^{r^2\cos(2\theta)}.$$

I'm not sure how to continue. I think that I have to find $(r,\theta)$ that maximizes the value of $|f(z)|$. Now, $\cos(2\theta)$ with $\theta\in[0,2\pi[$ reaches a maximum for $\theta = \pi/2$. This means that $z=ri, 0\le r\le 2$ and $|f(z)|=2re^{r^2}$. And this is maximized for $r=2$. In conclusion, $\max_{z\in\bar{B}(0,2)}|f(z)|=4e^4$.

Is this a correct approach? Thanks.

Comment: Assuming that $|f(z)|$ is as you claim (I didn't check your work), then this is equivalent to maximizing the function $g(x,y)=2xe^{x^2\cos(2y)}$ on $[-2,2]\times[0,2\pi]$.  This is potentially a Calc III problem using the second partial derivative test.  Did you try that yet? EDIT:  Also I bet you can make it simpler using the max modulus principle.

Comment: I checked and you seem to be missing a term $-r^2\sin(2\theta)$ in the exponential of $|f(z)|$

Comment: By max modulus, this reduces to maximizing $F(x)=4\exp[4\cos(2x)-4\sin(2x)]$ on $[0,2\pi]$. Take $F'(x)=-32[\cos(2x)+\sin(2x)]$ $\exp[(4\cos(2x)-4\sin(2x))]$ so that $F'(x)=0$ precisely when $-\frac{1}{8}(\pi+4n\pi)$, where $n=-4,-3,-2,-1,0$. That gives seven values to check and compare.

Comment: Agree with Jean-Claude Collete re: $\sin(2\theta)$. Afterwards it becomes a two variable maximisation on a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ just like everyone else said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $\overline B(0,2) = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| \le 2\} $, thanks to the [maximum modulus principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle) we can say the maximum of $|f(z)|$ is reached for $z=2e^{i\theta}$ for $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$.

Evaluating $|f(z)|$ for $z=2e^{i\theta}$ we get $|f(2e^{i\theta})| = 4e^{4(\cos(2\theta) - \sin(2\theta))}$
which is maximized when $\cos(2\theta) - \sin(2\theta)$ reaches his max: $$\max(\cos(2\theta) - \sin(2\theta)) = \sqrt{2} \quad \text{for} \quad  \theta = \pi n + \arctan(1-\sqrt2) \approx_{n=1} 2.74 \in [0,2\pi)$$

In conclusion: $$\max|f(z)| = 4e^{4\sqrt2}$$

**Edit:**

\begin{split}
|f(z)| & = |2ir|\cdot |e^{i\theta}| \cdot |e^{ir^2e^{2i\theta}}| \cdot |e^{r^2e^{2i\theta}}| \cdot |e^{2i}| \\
& = 2r \cdot |e^{ir^2[\cos(2\theta) +i\sin(2\theta)]}| \cdot |e^{r^2[\cos(2\theta) +i\sin(2\theta)]}| \\
& = 2r \cdot |e^{ir^2\cos(2\theta)}| \cdot |e^{-r^2\sin(2\theta)}| \cdot |e^{r^2cos(2\theta)}| + \cdot |e^{ir^2\sin(2\theta)]}| \\
& =2r \cdot |e^{-r^2\sin(2\theta) +r^2 \cos(2\theta)}|
\end{split}